# 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable Files are not properly selected

Tags: python, arrays, file, numpy, simplejson

I've the following piece of code.

```
fw = open(os.path.join(result_folder, 'motor_commands.txt'),'w')

np.set_printoptions(precision=3)

for positioner in positioner_grid.positioners[1:]:
    simplejson.dump(('Positioner ' + str(positioner.ident)), fw)
    fw.write('\n')
    array = np.array(positioner.motor1.position_array) * 180/math.pi
    array = np.round(array, decimals=4)
    simplejson.dump(array.tolist(), fw)
    fw.write('\n')
    array = np.array(positioner.motor2.position_array) * 180/math.pi
    array = np.round(array, decimals=4)
    simplejson.dump(array.tolist(), fw)
    fw.write('\n \n')
fw.close()
```

Its output is a `motor_commands.txt` whose layout (for example, for 2 positioners) is like this (the following symbolic entries are in fact numbers):

```
"Positioner 1"
[P11, P12, P13]
[Q11, Q12, Q13]

"Positioner 2"
[P21, P22, P23]
[Q21, Q22, Q23]
```

Given a pre-defined variable `dt`, I need to generate another file called `trajectories.yaml` whose format shall be like this:

```
1:
    alpha: [[P11,0*dt],[P12,1*dt],[P13,2*dt]]
    beta:  [[Q11,0*dt],[Q12,1*dt],[Q13,2*dt]]
2:
    alpha: [[P21,0*dt],[P22,1*dt],[P23,2*dt]]
    beta:  [[Q21,0*dt],[Q22,1*dt],[Q23,2*dt]]
```

So, here is what I've tried so far to generate the layout above.

```
    tw = open(os.path.join(result_folder, 'trajectories.yaml'), 'w')

    for positioner in positioner_grid.positioners[1:]:
        simplejson.dump((str(positioner.ident) + ':'), tw)
        tw.write('\n')
        simplejson.dump(('alpha: '), tw)
        position1 = []
        for i in range(1, len(positioner.motor1.position_array)):
            temp = [positioner.motor1.position_array[i] * 180 / math.pi, (i-1) * dt]
            position1.append(temp)
        simplejson.dump(array[position1].tolist(), tw)
        tw.write('\n')
        simplejson.dump(('beta: '), tw)
        position2 = []
        for i in range(1, len(positioner.motor2.position_array)):
            temp = [positioner.motor2.position_array[i] * 180 / math.pi, (i-1) * dt]
            position2.append(temp)
        simplejson.dump(array[position2].tolist(), tw)
        tw.write('\n')
    tw.close()
```

But the following error is thrown:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable Files are not properly selected.
```

and my `trajectories.yaml` file is not generated correctly:

```
"1:"
"alpha: "
```

What am I doing wrong, if you please?

Comment: typo: `array(position1)` should be `array[position1]`.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: I fixed the typo, but the error and the output yaml file are as the same.

Comment: There are a few typos like that. Once there are no more typos, I would advise to create a [mcve] that shows the problem in a new question.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: I just wanted to send an `MWE`, but I have no right access to share the whole code to present an `MWE`. :(

Comment: The issue is that with what you have in this question, the only thing we can say is that you had a typo and it's now fixed. The error is probably now different, the file contains other lines and probably other things are missing as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to be sure, but I believe that your problem would be solved as follows.

```
tw = open(os.path.join(result_folder, 'trajectories.yaml'), 'w')

for positioner in positioner_grid.positioners[1:]:
    tw.write(str(positioner.ident) + ':')
    tw.write('\n')
    tw.write('    alpha: ')
    position1 = []
    for i in range(0, len(positioner.motor1.position_array)):
        temp = [positioner.motor1.position_array[i] * 180 / math.pi, i * dt]
        position1.append(temp)
    simplejson.dump(position1, tw)
    tw.write('\n')
    tw.write('    beta: ')
    position2 = []
    for i in range(0, len(positioner.motor2.position_array)):
        temp = [positioner.motor2.position_array[i] * 180 / math.pi, i * dt]
        position2.append(temp)
    simplejson.dump(position2, tw)
    tw.write('\n')
tw.close()
```

This code can be shortened considerably if we use `math.degrees()`, `enumerate()`, and list comprehensions. Moreover, the preferred idiom for `open()` is `with open(...):` which guarantees the file will be closed.

With this in mind, the above can be rewritten as:

```
import math

with open(os.path.join(result_folder, 'trajectories.yaml'), 'w') as tw:
    for p in positioner_grid.positioners[1:]:
        tw.write(str(p.ident) + ':\n    alpha: ')
        position1 = [[math.degrees(pos), i * dt] for i, pos in enumerate(p.motor1.position_array)]
        simplejson.dump(position1, tw)
        tw.write('\n    beta: ')
        position2 = [[math.degrees(pos), i * dt] for i, pos in enumerate(p.motor2.position_array)]
        simplejson.dump(position2, tw)
        tw.write('\n')
```

Comment: This works. Best practices though... Consider using `math.degrees()` and `enumerate`... and list comprehensions... and `with open(...):`...